# Error with mvn test: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scalatest

I am getting the following error only when running all the test cases using `mvn test`. This doesn't happen if I run each of the test classes independently from IDE. I am using `https://github.com/MrPowers/spark-fast-tests` framework.

**Trait**

```
trait SparkSessionTestWrapper {

  lazy val spark: SparkSession = {
    SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("spark-fast-tests test session")
      .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "1")
      .getOrCreate()
  }
}
```

**Tests**

*WordCountDSAppTestSpec*

```
class WordCountDSAppTestSpec extends FlatSpec with SparkSessionTestWrapper with DatasetComparer {

  import spark.implicits._

  "toWords" should "split the file into words" in {
    val sourceDf = Seq(
      ("one"),
      ("two"),
      (""),
      ("three Three")
    ).toDF("line").as[Line]

    val expectedDF = Seq(
      ("one", "one"),
      ("two", "two"),
      ("three Three", "three"),
      ("three Three", "Three"),
      ("", "")
    ).toDF("line", "word").as[LineAndWord]

    val actualDF = WordCountDSApp.toWords(sourceDf)

    assertSmallDatasetEquality(actualDF, expectedDF, orderedComparison = false)
  }

  "countWords" should "return count of each word" in {

    val wordsDF = Seq(
      ("one", "one"),
      ("two", "two"),
      ("three Three", "three"),
      ("three Three", "Three"),
      ("", "")
    ).toDF("line", "word").as[LineAndWord]

    val tupleEncoder = Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING, Encoders.LONG)
    val expectedDF = Seq(
      ("one", 1L),
      ("two", 1L),
      ("three", 2L)
    ).toDF("value", "count(1)").as[(String, Long)]

    val actualDF = WordCountDSApp.countWords(wordsDF)

    assertSmallDatasetEquality(actualDF, expectedDF, orderedComparison = false)
  }
}
```

*ProductSalesAppTestSpec*

```
class ProductSalesAppTestSpec extends FlatSpec with SparkSessionTestWrapper with DatasetComparer {

  import spark.implicits._

  val productCols = Seq("product_id", "product_name", "price")
  val productDF = Seq(
    ("0", "product_0", "22"),
    ("1", "product_1", "30"),
    ("2", "product_2", "91")
  ).toDF(productCols: _*)
  productDF.createOrReplaceTempView("PRODUCTS")

  val orderCols = Seq("order_id", "product_id", "seller_id", "date", "num_pieces_sold", "bill_raw_text")

  "howManyProductsHaveBeenSoldAtLeastOnce" should "return zero when no orders are made for products" in {
    val orderDF = Seq(
      ("1", "10", "0", "2020-07-10", "26", "kyeibuumwlyhuwksx"),
      ("2", "20", "0", "2020-07-08", "13", "kyeibuumwlyhuwksx"),
      ("3", "30", "0", "2020-07-05", "38", "kyeibuumwlyhuwksx"),
      ("4", "40", "0", "2020-07-05", "56", "kyeibuumwlyhuwksx")
    ).toDF(orderCols: _*)
    orderDF.createOrReplaceTempView("ORDERS")

    assert(ProductSalesApp.howManyProductsHaveBeenAoldAtLeastOnce(spark) == 0)
  }
}
```

**Error**

```
- should return zero when no orders are made for products *** FAILED ***
  org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
  at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:226)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec.doExecuteBroadcast(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:146)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.doExecuteBroadcast(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:387)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:144)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeBroadcast(SparkPlan.scala:140)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.prepareBroadcast(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:117)
  ...
  Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
This stopped SparkContext was created at:

org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
com.aravind.oss.SparkSessionTestWrapper$class.spark(SparkSessionTestWrapper.scala:16)
com.aravind.oss.eg.spark.sales.ProductSalesAppTestSpec.spark$lzycompute(ProductSalesAppTestSpec.scala:13)
com.aravind.oss.eg.spark.sales.ProductSalesAppTestSpec.spark(ProductSalesAppTestSpec.scala:13)
com.aravind.oss.eg.spark.sales.ProductSalesAppTestSpec.<init>(ProductSalesAppTestSpec.scala:18)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
org.scalatest.tools.DiscoverySuite$.getSuiteInstance(DiscoverySuite.scala:66)
org.scalatest.tools.DiscoverySuite$$anonfun$1.apply(DiscoverySuite.scala:38)
org.scalatest.tools.DiscoverySuite$$anonfun$1.apply(DiscoverySuite.scala:37)
scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)

The currently active SparkContext was created at:

org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
com.aravind.oss.SparkSessionTestWrapper$class.spark(SparkSessionTestWrapper.scala:16)
com.aravind.oss.eg.spark.wordcount.WordCountDSAppTestSpec.spark$lzycompute(WordCountDSAppTestSpec.scala:15)
com.aravind.oss.eg.spark.wordcount.WordCountDSAppTestSpec.spark(WordCountDSAppTestSpec.scala:15)
com.aravind.oss.eg.spark.wordcount.WordCountDSAppTestSpec$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(WordCountDSAppTestSpec.scala:20)
com.aravind.oss.eg.spark.wordcount.WordCountDSAppTestSpec$$anonfun$1.apply(WordCountDSAppTestSpec.scala:19)
com.aravind.oss.eg.spark.wordcount.WordCountDSAppTestSpec$$anonfun$1.apply(WordCountDSAppTestSpec.scala:19)
org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anon$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1682)
org.scalatest.TestSuite$class.withFixture(TestSuite.scala:196)
org.scalatest.FlatSpec.withFixture(FlatSpec.scala:1685)
org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.invokeWithFixture$1(FlatSpecLike.scala:1679)
org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1692)
org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1692)
org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:286)
org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.runTest(FlatSpecLike.scala:1692)
org.scalatest.FlatSpec.runTest(FlatSpec.scala:1685)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.assertNotStopped(SparkContext.scala:100)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.defaultParallelism(SparkContext.scala:2359)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LocalTableScanExec.numParallelism$lzycompute(LocalTableScanExec.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LocalTableScanExec.numParallelism(LocalTableScanExec.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LocalTableScanExec.rdd$lzycompute(LocalTableScanExec.scala:51)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LocalTableScanExec.rdd(LocalTableScanExec.scala:51)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LocalTableScanExec.doExecute(LocalTableScanExec.scala:55)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your [git repo](https://github.com/yaravind/learn-spark/tree/master/stackoverflow-complete)

after entering in to this test case

```
  "howManyProductsHaveBeenSoldAtLeastOnce" should "return zero when no orders are made for products" in {
```

It is resetting(stopping the spark context ) your spark session by using new thread via `mvn test` when you are using spark session from trait.

where as from Itellij IDE its in the same thread and its not resetting spark (not stopping the context)

I was able to investigate in mvn debug mode (`mvn -DforkMode=never test -f pom.xml`) and with the usage of `spark.sparkContext.isStopped` as shown in the below code.

Thats the reason its working from [intellij](/questions/tagged/intellij) and not via `mvn test`

---

So I left the idea of creating trait for spark session  and created a local spark session (may be you can try for `import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll}`) for better code.

```
package com.aravind.oss.eg.spark.wordcount

import com.aravind.oss.SparkSessionTestWrapper
import com.aravind.oss.eg.spark.sales.ProductSalesApp
import com.github.mrpowers.spark.fast.tests.DatasetComparer
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, FlatSpec}
import ProductSalesApp._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
class ProductSalesAppTestSpec extends FlatSpec   with DatasetComparer {


   lazy  implicit val spark: SparkSession =
    SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("spark-fast-tests test session")
      .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "1")
      .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._
  val productCols = Seq("product_id", "product_name", "price")
  val productDF = Seq(
    ("0", "product_0", "22"),
    ("1", "product_1", "30"),
    ("2", "product_2", "91")
  ).toDF(productCols: _*)
  productDF.createOrReplaceTempView("PRODUCTS")

  val orderCols = Seq("order_id", "product_id", "seller_id", "date", "num_pieces_sold", "bill_raw_text")
  val orderDF = Seq(
    ("1", "10", "0", "2020-07-10", "26", "kyeibuumwlyhuwksx"),
    ("2", "20", "0", "2020-07-08", "13", "kyeibuumwlyhuwksx"),
    ("3", "30", "0", "2020-07-05", "38", "kyeibuumwlyhuwksx"),
    ("4", "40", "0", "2020-07-05", "56", "kyeibuumwlyhuwksx")
  ).toDF(orderCols: _*)
  orderDF.createOrReplaceTempView("ORDERS")
  orderDF.show
  println(  spark.sparkContext.isStopped)
  println(  spark.sparkContext.isLocal)
  "howManyProductsHaveBeenSoldAtLeastOnce" should "return zero when no orders are made for products" in {

    println( "howManyProductsHaveBeenSoldAtLeastOnce "+ spark.sparkContext.isStopped)
    println(  spark.sparkContext.isLocal)
    println(ProductSalesApp.howManyProductsHaveBeenAoldAtLeastOnce(spark))
    assert(ProductSalesApp.howManyProductsHaveBeenAoldAtLeastOnce(spark) == 0)

  }
}
```

Result :

```
+--------+----------+---------+----------+---------------+-----------------+
|order_id|product_id|seller_id|      date|num_pieces_sold|    bill_raw_text|
+--------+----------+---------+----------+---------------+-----------------+
|       1|        10|        0|2020-07-10|             26|kyeibuumwlyhuwksx|
|       2|        20|        0|2020-07-08|             13|kyeibuumwlyhuwksx|
|       3|        30|        0|2020-07-05|             38|kyeibuumwlyhuwksx|
|       4|        40|        0|2020-07-05|             56|kyeibuumwlyhuwksx|
+--------+----------+---------+----------+---------------+-----------------+

false
true
howManyProductsHaveBeenSoldAtLeastOnce false
true
0
```

Comment: Are you getting the same error when you run the tests with  mvn -DforkMode=never test ?

Comment: yes same error  with local spark session (with out your trait ) its working

Comment: I am still wondering at what part of the code the sparkCtx is stopped! I am not sure yet on who is stopping to context. Do you have any idea?

Comment: after entering   `howManyProductsHaveBeenSoldAtLeastOnce" should "return zero when no orders are made for products" in {
`  spark context is stopped since active thread local changed some how.

Comment: I have done extensive research :-) and What i understood is spark session is working with thread-local variable. since its changing in this case its stopping the sparksession.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "since its changing in this case its stopping the sparksession"! Can you add more details on "what is changing?" and "who is stopping it??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212098/discussion-between-aravind-yarram-and-ram-ghadiyaram).